# Add more then one Python Selenium WebDriverWait exception to download an element

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement

So I have this in my script:

```
today = datetime.now()
today = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d")
y_yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)
y_yesterday = y_yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d")
y2_yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3)
y2_yesterday = y2_yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d")
y3_yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=4)
y3_yesterday = y3_yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d")
exp = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_"+today+".xls']"
exp_y = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_"+yesterday+".xls']"
exp_y2 = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_"+y_yesterday+".xls']"
exp_y3 = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_"+y2_yesterday+".xls']"
```

Basicaly, I want to download an xls file from the web site. I want to automate this process using crontab scheduler.
Problem is, that the file I want to download is uploaded at random dates and not event at random hour, but sometimes they forget to upload it for even 2 or 3 days (automation vs. manual job :) )

For now I am using this:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("%s" % exp)))).click()
    nazwa = 'Some_excel_to_download_'+today+'.xls'
    print(nazwa)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Today's file not found. Trying: " + exp_y)
    exp = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_"+yesterday+".xls']"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_y).click()
    nazwa = 'Some_excel_to_download_'+yesterday+'.xls'
    print(nazwa)
```

and this works fine, as long as a xls file is one day old...I want to know, how to add more "except" statements or (I guess it's better option) something like "if, elif, else" statement, but I am not sure how to do it... Maybe you could help me there, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `if condition` to check the `length of the elements` if the elements length `count more than 0` then click on the element else go the next statement and check the same.

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(exp))>0:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp).click()
elif len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(exp_y))>0:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_y).click()
elif len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(exp_y2))>0:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_y2).click()
elif len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(exp_y3))>0:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_y3).click()
else:
    print("No such elements")
```

---

Or you can use nested `try..except` block removed the `TimeoutException` exception .

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("%s" % exp)))).click()
    nazwa = 'Some_excel_to_download_'+today+'.xls'
    print(nazwa)
except:
    try:
       print("Today's file not found. Trying: " + exp_y)
       exp = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_"+yesterday+".xls']"
       driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_y).click()
       nazwa = 'Some_excel_to_download_'+yesterday+'.xls'
       print(nazwa)
    except:
        try:
           print("Today's file not found. Trying: " + exp_y2)
           exp = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_" + y_yesterday + ".xls']"
           driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_y2).click()
           nazwa = 'Some_excel_to_download_' + y_yesterday + '.xls'
           print(nazwa)
        except:
            print("Today's file not found. Trying: " + exp_y3)
            exp = "//*[@title='Some_excel_to_download_" + y2_yesterday + ".xls']"
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_y3).click()
            nazwa = 'Some_excel_to_download_' + y2_yesterday + '.xls'
            print(nazwa)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @Kunduk.
Nested try fails if won't find element after 2nd try.
Regarding if, where should I put WebDriverWait ? Basically, website needs few seconds to load list of downloadable elements, without it it simply searches on "loading page" and finds nothing.

Comment: @IrkaIrenka: Just only use except.Removed `TimeoutException`.This should work fine.I have updated.If you would like to use if statement just put `time.sleep(10)` to wait for the element to load.

Comment: :) I have also tried adding:
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("%s" % exp_y3)))).click()
except TimeoutException:
and added variables and it work. MAny thanks KunduK !:)

Comment: Great to know that.